# Change tag of selection

Tags: javascript, dom, coffeescript, ckeditor

Here's an interesting problem. I want the user to be able to select multiple elements and choose a new tag for them by clicking a button. My current code looks like this:

```
sel = editor.getSelection()
ranges = sel.getRanges()
# Iterate through the selection ranges
for range in ranges
    iterator = range.createIterator()
    paragraphs = []
    # Iterate through the blocks in the range
    while (block = iterator.getNextParagraph())
        # Undo the style if it's already applied 
        if (block.getName() == tagName) 
            tagName = 'p'
        paragraphs.push( block )
    if paragraphs.length
        # Create the new element
        bqBlock = editor.document.createElement(tagName)
        bqBlock.insertBefore( paragraphs[0] )
        # Move each child in the selection into the new element
        while ( paragraphs.length > 0 )
            block = paragraphs.shift()
            block.moveChildren(bqBlock)
            block.remove()
```

This works great, except the selection goes erased, which is horribly user-unfriendly. I'd like to maintain the original selection.

I'm using ckeditor if there's a built-in way to do this.

Edit:

Reinmar found the answer for me:
[Set cursor to specific position in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor/16859577)

Comment: You'll find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor/16859577#16859577

Comment: Thanks that answers it! - Marked as duplicate