# CKEditor what to get cursor position and set again after replacing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to set cursor position manually to specific position in **CKEditor**. I have implemented short keys on some key press i am adding text using set data in **CKEditor** (e.g. if i type "RnD+Space", it will replace with "research and development "). The problem is that after set data cursor will set to last at the end of all text.

I want cursor will be there, where the text is replaced. Is this possible?

Comment: I have tried with insertHTML but not able to remove existing text(ex. if i have typed "eo+Space", then it will insert "Evolution of+Space" the word will become "eo Evolution of ").

Comment: I have almost done. I have some complication. Please check my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910435/ck-editor-find-and-replace-will-works-only-first-time-then-it-will-gives-index-e

Comment: I think This answer on stack-overflow might help you.


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor