# CK editor find and replace will works only first time then it will gives index error in ranges[0].setStart function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

CK editor find and replace will work only first time then it always gives index error in `ranges[0].setStart` function.
I have tried with `editor.updateElement();` but it's not working.

```
function test() {
       try {
           var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[("<%=ckDescription.ClientID %>")];
           var sel = editor.getSelection();

           var element = sel.getStartElement();
           sel.selectElement(element);
           var findString = 'FE';
           var ranges = editor.getSelection().getRanges();

           var startIndex = element.getText().indexOf(findString);
           if (startIndex != -1) {
               ranges[0].setStart(element.getFirst(), startIndex);
               ranges[0].setEnd(element.getFirst(), startIndex + findString.length);
               sel.selectRanges([ranges[0]]);
           }


           var range = sel.getRanges()[0];
           range.deleteContents();
           range.select();

           editor.insertText('For Example');
           editor.updateElement();

       }
       catch (e) {
           alert(e);
           return false;
       }
       return false;


   }
```

**Error :**

> IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 36
>   is larger than or equal to the node's length (17).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each and every time before creating ckeditor instance you should try this
                            CKEDITOR.instances={}

Sometime CKEDITOR.instance object use to hold the previous instances as object property, so next time find and replace function stop working because of the previous instance with the same named property. So the only solution is to destroy the previous instance. One way is to call

editor.destroy() / CKEDITOR.instances.("<%=ckDescription.ClientID %>").destroy()

Comment: This answer does not seem to have anything in common with the question. The question on the other hand falls into the "why isn't this code working?" category, so answering it does not make sense :).