# Position cursor inside tags in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, youtube, tags, cursor, ckeditor

I am trying to create a custom tag and have the cursor set between opening tag and closing tag. Something like this: **[youtube]**{cursor_here}**[/youtube]**.

I have something like this so far:

```
            var selectedText = editor.getSelection().getNative(); 
            if(selectedText === null ){
                //ToDo: add youtube tag with cursor positioned in the middle
            } else {
                var openTag = '[youtube]';
                var closeTag = '[/youtube]<br />';
                editor.insertHtml(openTag + selectedText + closeTag);
            }
```

I also tried the approach with `editor.insertElement` but I couldn't get it solved out with custom tags.

The idea behind this is to have the user ready to paste a link (like a youtube link) after he pressed a custom button that inserts the tag. Without external dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor)

Looks like this:

```
            var sel = editor.getSelection();
            var ranges = sel.getRanges();
            var inserted = ranges[0].startContainer.getNext();
            ranges[0].setStart(inserted, 9);
            ranges[0].setEnd(inserted, 9);
            sel.selectRanges([ranges[0]]);
```