# How to place content at the caret position in ck editor

Tags: ckeditor, liferay

I am using ck editor in my custom portlet.Liferay version 6.2 CE
I want to place content in the caret position in ck editor with ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setData](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData) method from CKEditor's API for replace existing data:

```
$.ajax("url")
.done(function(data) {
    CKEDITOR.instances["<instance_name>"].setData(data);
});
```

For insert data into current caret position is method [insertHtml](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml):

```
$.ajax("url")
.done(function(data) {
    CKEDITOR.instances["<instance_name>"].insertHtml(data);
});
```

Good explanation for setting caret position is in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835365/set-cursor-to-specific-position-in-ckeditor)

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, But this will remove the existing data in ck editor,and with setData how can caret position is set.

Comment: My question is  How to get the caret position.

Comment: It is explained in that thread, getting/setting caret position using [ranges](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range). Using this `CKEDITOR.instances["<instance_name>"].getSelection().getRanges()` you have Object with information about selection, if nothing is selected, this information is about caret position (selection with length 0).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for the answer but. the Api is a bit different in Liferay compared with ck editor.

The methods insertHtml and get ranges are not there in  Liferay ck editor